# Moshi with Retrofit send empty request

Tags: java, android, kotlin, retrofit, mosh

My app send my location every time. when I disable geolocation. i want send {"latitude":null,"longitude":null} but sent {}

Model

```
@Serializable
data class PointBody(
    @Json(name = "latitude") val latitude: Double?,
    @Json(name = "longitude") val longitude: Double?
)
```

Request

```
 @POST(Path.LOCATION)
    suspend fun sendPoint(
        @Body point: PointBody
    )
```

Retorift

```
private fun provideRetrofit(moshi: Moshi, client: OkHttpClient) = Retrofit.Builder()
    .client(client)
    .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create(moshi))
    .baseUrl("Base")
    .build()
```

Moshi

```
private fun provideMoshi(): Moshi {
    return Moshi
        .Builder()
        .add(KotlinJsonAdapterFactory())
        .build()
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve just adding `withNullSerialization()` function to `MoshiConverterFactory`.

```kotlin
    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideMoshi(): Moshi =
        Moshi.Builder()
            .add(KotlinJsonAdapterFactory())
            .build()
    
    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideMoshiConverterFactory(moshi: Moshi): MoshiConverterFactory =
        MoshiConverterFactory.create(moshi).withNullSerialization()
```

Code From `MoshiConverterFactory.java`

```java
...
  /** Return a new factory which includes null values into the serialized JSON. */
  public MoshiConverterFactory withNullSerialization() {
    return new MoshiConverterFactory(moshi, lenient, failOnUnknown, true);
  }
...
```

Please check [MoshiConverterFactory.java](https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/372e8ba81f6cd219267d3ecb0e0c5732c08bdc6c/retrofit-converters/moshi/src/main/java/retrofit2/converter/moshi/MoshiConverterFactory.java) for further information.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

My solution

Factory

```
@kotlin.annotation.Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
@JsonQualifier
annotation class SerializeNulls

class SerializeNullsFactory : JsonAdapter.Factory {
    override fun create(type: Type, annotations: Set<Annotation?>, moshi: Moshi): JsonAdapter<*>? {
        val nextAnnotations = Types.nextAnnotations(
            annotations,
            SerializeNulls::class.java
        ) ?: return null
        return moshi.nextAdapter<Any>(this, type, nextAnnotations).serializeNulls()
    }
}
```

Model

```
@Serializable
data class PointBody(
    @SerializeNulls val latitude: Double?,
    @SerializeNulls val longitude: Double?
)
```

Moshi

```
private fun provideMoshi(): Moshi {
    return Moshi
        .Builder()
        .add(SerializeNullsFactory())
        .add(KotlinJsonAdapterFactory())
        .build()
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).